# How to show print dialog in wpf controll

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, print-preview

I have Printer class that derived from PrintDialog class and I use this class to print document. How can I show this document in Print Preview Control from Windows Forms? It works in Windows Forms, but doesn't in WPF.

I have control in XAML:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Margin="242,6,144,20">
    <wf:PrintPreviewControl x:Name="ppcShow" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

and code:

```
Printer p = new Printer();
ppcShow.Document = p;
```

How to show documents data?

Comment: WPF provide rich API to handling printing, here you can find the sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742418(v=vs.110).aspx